# Битрикс. Как сделать автоматическую отработку события "нажатие кнопки" при загрузки страницы?

Tags: php, битрикс

В фильтре инфоблока есть кнопка "Найти". Как сделать автоматическую отработку этого события? можно это сделать из кода php (iblock_element_admin.php)
Код кнопки:

```html
$oFilter->Buttons();
?><span class="adm-btn-wrap"><input type="submit"  class="adm-btn" name="set_filter" value="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_set_butt"); ?>" title="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_set_butt_title"); ?>" onClick="return applyFilter(this);"></span>
<span class="adm-btn-wrap"><input type="submit"  class="adm-btn" name="del_filter" value="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_clear_butt"); ?>" title="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_clear_butt_title"); ?>" onClick="deleteFilter(this); return false;"></span>
<?
$oFilter->End();
?>
```

Comment: А для чего именно нужна такая реализация? Bitrix ведь при фильтрации формирует url с необходимыми параметрами, можно просто отправлять юзера по этому урлу. Или когда нужна автоматическая отработка? Когда пользователь выбрал что - то в фильтре? Если так, то можно отследить скриптом событие на изменение инпутов в форме фильтра и сабмитить её при этом самом изменении.

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов Нет, я создаю фильтр инфоблока, который будет фильтровать элементы  по id пользователя автоматически (чего не предусмотрел битрикс) без возможности этот фильтр убрать. Фильтр срабатывает через эту кнопку "найти" вот и нужно организовать это срабатывание как только пользователь перешел на страницу инфоблока.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно трогать файл ядра не хорошо, поэтому повесь обработчик на событие, аля "OnAdminTabControlBegin" к примеру в init.php

```
AddEventHandler('main', 'OnAdminTabControlBegin', 'OnAdminTabControlBeginHandler');
```

внутри обработчика используя

```
$GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetCurPage()
```

определи в нужном месте ли находится пользователь, и затем после условия можешь использовать такую конструкцию:

```
<?ob_start();?>
<script>
  // логика js скрипта, тут можешь вешать триггеры и т.п., что угодно
</script>
<?
$sContent = ob_get_clean();
$GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->AddHeadString($sContent);
?>
```

в итоге при загрузке нужной страницы, будет вставляться в хэдер твой js код, через который ты можешь указать чтобы он триггерил нажатие кнопки и т.п.

Если конкретно твой случай, то получается, можно в js коде добавить:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=set_filter]').trigger('click');
})
```