# Как вызвать событие нажатие кнопки "найти", при загрузке страницы в фильтре инфоблока битрикс

Tags: php, javascript, html, битрикс

На странице инфоблока есть фильтр, нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на страницу инфоблока вызывалось событие нажатия кнопки "найти" (**пользователь переходит на страницу инфоблока,а фильтр сразу срабатывал без нажатия кнопки "найти"**). Помогите пожалуйста реализовать

```html
$oFilter->Buttons();
?><span class="adm-btn-wrap"><input type="submit" id="btn1" class="adm-btn" name="set_filter" value="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_set_butt"); ?>" title="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_set_butt_title"); ?>"  onClick="return applyFilter(this);"></span>
<span class="adm-btn-wrap"><input type="submit"  class="adm-btn" name="del_filter" value="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_clear_butt"); ?>" title="<? echo GetMessage("admin_lib_filter_clear_butt_title"); ?>" onClick="deleteFilter(this); return false;"></span>
```

Прошу вашей помощи, уже какой день гадаю как это сделать((

Comment: В первую очередь поставить для самого себя правильно задачу. Что значит "сразу нажать найти"? Вы хотите перезагрузить страницу? Поясните "зачем". Потому что при такой постановке вопроса сама задача кажется бредом.

Comment: Или речь про админку?

Comment: Да. Но я уже реализовал. Если интересно как могу скинуть код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Битрикс. Как сделать автоматическую отработку события "нажатие кнопки" при загрузки страницы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652374/%d0%91%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

Можно "нажать" кнопку при помощи Яваскрипт. jQuery, например: Загрузить jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click();
    });
</script>
```